# Connecting to the database using function from separated file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

I have simple form to add records to database. It look like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Student Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="stu_name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name"/><br /><br />
<label>Student Email :</label>
<input type="email" name="stu_email" id="email" required="required" placeholder="john123@gmail.com"/><br/><br />
<label>Student City :</label>
<input type="text" name="stu_city" id="city" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Your City"/><br/><br />
<input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$hostname='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=college",$username,$password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
    $sql = "INSERT INTO students (student_name, student_email, student_city)
    VALUES ('".$_POST["stu_name"]."','".$_POST["stu_email"]."','".$_POST["stu_city"]."')";
    if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
    }

    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

}
?>
```

This code works, i can connect to the database and add some records. My question is, what do I have to change in that code, if I want to connect to the database using code from the other file instead of the connection from the first code:

```
<?php

class Database {

public function getConnection() {
    $result = false;
    try {
        $result = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=college', 'root', '');
    } catch(PDOException $e) { }
    return $result;
}
}
$db = new Database();
$conn = $db->getConnection();
if (!$conn) {
die("Error connecting to the database");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the database script and then use `$conn` for all database operations, instead of creating the new PDO object and using `$dbh`.

```
require_once('database.php');

try {
  if ($conn->query($sql)) {
      ...
      ...
   }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Side note: your query is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use a [Prepared Statement](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating values into the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the database class with the php require statement.

```
    <?php
        // file: database.class.php
        class Database {
            ...
        }
    ?>
```

And another file

```
    <?php
        // file another_file.php
        require('./your/path/to/Database.class.php');
        $db = new Database();
        $connection = $db->getConnection();
    ?>
```